# DOM redraw being blocked by childProcess.spawnSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, synchronization, electron

I have an electron/node.js app that I'm having trouble with.  Specifically, I need to give the user some feedback on the progress of a long loop of synchronous spawns by updating an element in the DOM. However, what is actually displayed does not change during the loop. Once the entire loop is complete, the element does update with the final `max` index value.

```
function dosomething(index,callback) {
   childProcess.spawnSync('app1',...  //takes 1 second
   childProcess.spawnSync('app2',...  //takes 6 seconds, depends on app1 running 1st
   console.log('working on: ' + index);
   callback(index);
}

function dosomethingelse(index) {
    $('#somediv').html(index);  //update progress bar
    console.log('displaying: ' + $('#somediv').html());
}

for(var i=0; i<max; i++){ //max is usually 10-100, loop takes 1 to 10 minutes
    dosomething(i,dosomethingelse);
}
```

When I dump the progress html to the console, it does increment with index as a callback:

```
CONSOLE:
working on: 0
displaying: 0
working on: 1
displaying: 1
working on: 2
displaying: 2
...
```

Also, I have tried to force redraw the div by running the following code to no avail:

```
function dosomethingelse(index) {
    $('#somediv').html(index);  //update progress bar
    console.log($('#somediv').html());
    //REDRAW
    document.getElementById("somediv").innerHTML =num;
    document.getElementById("somediv").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("somediv").offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("somediv").style.display = 'block';
}
```

From what I have read, using spawnSync makes my binary app run in blocking mode on nodejs. This is directly against the nonblocking core of node, but is absolutely necessary in my situation since my command line call runs for 6 seconds and takes nearly 100% CPU.  If I instead use the standard async spawn I end up with 50x 100% processes running simultaneously, finishing after a few minutes around the same time.  Again, no progress feedback provided to the user.  I don't understand why my callback is not being completed.  If I switch around the functions so that `dosomethingelse` is called first with a `dosomething` callback, I still get no DOM updates.

Two other things I have tried: [npm sleep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep):

```
dosomething(i);
var sleep = require('sleep');
sleep.usleep(100);
dosomethingelse(i);
```

And [deasync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync):

```
var deasync = require('deasync');
deasync(dosomething(i));
dosomethingelse(i);
```

Same result. Also, if I take out my long running `dosomething` function and replace it with a `sleep.sleep(3)` I get the same result.  Node is just going from one blocking task to the next without updating the UI.

Comment: I have thought about using a command line task spooler like this one: http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/~viric/soft/ts/, running all my heavy CPU tasks through that and then polling it every second to update my progress bar.  Problem with this approach is that it's not going to be cross platform (with this spooler at least).  I'll have to get more creative with the Windows port.

Comment: Just do it async and put'em in a promise queue?

Comment: Trying to update the chrome DOM that the user sees as part of the electron app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be only worried about too many async processes running at the same time. But in fact, you can control how many run at the same time.

For example like so:

```
function runTask(tasks, index, callback) {
  if (index >= tasks.length) {
    callback();
  }
  tasks[index](() => runTask(tasks, index + 1, callback));
}

function queue(tasks, callback) {
  runTask(tasks, 0, callback);
}
```

with this you'd have a simple way to queue your async spawns up:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function customSpawn(command, args) {
  return callback => {
    const child = spawn(command, args);
    child.on('close', callback);
  }
} 

queue([customSpawn('app1', []), customSpawn('app2', [])], dosomethingelse);
```

<sub>I never tested any of the above code and therefore I can not guarantee for its correctness.</sub>

Also, have a look at promises and generators if you want to get rid of all those callbacks.

For example with promises it might look like this:

```
function queue(tasks) {
  let index = 0;
  const runTask = arg => {
    if (index >= tasks.length) {
      return Promise.resolve(arg);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      tasks[index++](arg).then(arg => resolve(runTask(arg))).catch(reject);
    });
  };
  return runTask();
}

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function customSpawn(command, args) {
  return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const child = spawn(command, args);
    child.on('close', code => {
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
}

queue([customSpawn('app1', []), customSpawn('app2', [])])
  .then(dosomethingelse)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

[Try it!](https://jsfiddle.net/9ccdjxr0/)

A note regarding the for loop: Build the queue with what you want to do up first using closures as demonstrated in `customSpawn` and then pass it to `queue`.

Comment: wow, I'm not used to coding this way, node is a mindf#$%.  It'll take me a bit to implement this in my project and see if it is bueno.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by building the queue?  Do you mean set up the entire array of function calls (`customSpawn(...)` and `updateprogress(i)` etc) that have to run in a specific order then pass it to `queue`?  eg: `var myqueue=["customSpawn('app1', [])", "customSpawn('app2', [])","progress(i)"], ... etc`, then `queue(myqueue) ...`

Comment: @UltrasoundJelly right because otherwise, they'd all run at the same time again.

Comment: I see.  Because each queue() call is a new asynchronous command.

Comment: How would the functions communicate with each other, would I just have to set some global variables?

Comment: @UltrasoundJelly I improved the version which makes use of promises so that each function can pass arguments to the next function in the queue. You could also do something like that with the callback version.

Comment: OK,  I've rearranged my code and implemented your queue as above.  I've successfully built the spawn array with args, but when I try to run it I get the following error thrown to the console: `TypeError: tasks[(index++)] is not a function(…)`

Comment: Using the callback only version I'm getting a syntax error at the same spot: `tasks[index] is not a function`

Comment: I think your solution is brilliant, BTW.  I just need to debug this bit of code.

Comment: I guess I need to wrap my progress function in similar code as your customSpawn.  Maybe it's failing when it gets to that function in the queue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118232/discussion-between-mash-and-ultrasoundjelly).